# Compilation error on compiling Xamarin Forms iOS project

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-app-center

We are getting the following error on compiling our Xamarin Forms iOS project through App Center Build environment.

We are struggling to understand the root cause of this error. More so because this project was compiling earlier. The only changes we have done (since the previous successfully compilation) is update to the latest version of Xamarin Forms library as well as latest version of Visual Studio.

MTOUCH : error **MT2101**: Can't resolve the reference 'System.Void UIKit.UIDatePicker::**set_PreferredDatePickerStyle**(UIKit.UIDatePickerStyle)', referenced from the method 'System.Void Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.DatePickerRendererBase`1::OnElementChanged(Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ElementChangedEventArgs`1<Xamarin.Forms.DatePicker>)' in 'Xamarin.iOS, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065'. [/Users/runner/work/1/s/USR_Practice/USR_Practice.iOS/USR_Practice.iOS.csproj]

Since we do not have a MAC, we depend on Appcenter for the iOS builds. Is this is a problem with our project/code OR with Appcenter. How can we resolve it?

Comment: The first hit I get in Google indicates that you should update the Mono version used by your build pipeline

Comment: Thanks Jason. Please guide whether we can change Mono version within Xamarin iOS project settings OR we need to inform this to App enter.

Comment: Did you update the Xamrin.forms nuget package in your ios project at the same time ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AppCenter Build has an option to tell the version of Xamarin iOS SDK to be used for build. This needs to be updated manually everytime a new Xamarin iOS SDK build is out. Else it continues to build with the previously/last set Version.

Once we update the AppCenter Build to build with latest SDK, all errors are resolved.